# OpenCPU server root directory

Tags: r, opencpu

What directory does the single-user OpenCPU server serve from, and if I have a webpage that uses OpenCPU JavaScript code, how do I make it run on my server? I want to avoid using CORS.

I've tried fooling around with `.opencpu.conf`, but no luck - there isn't anything there that specifies the server path, except for `"appspaths"`, changing which doesn't affect anything.

Further, as a side question - has anybody attempted installing the OpenCPU cloud server on Arch, and is the process more or less straightforward?

Thanks, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code into the `inst` dir of an R package and install that on your server. See one of the [example apps](https://github.com/opencpu) which are live here: https://www.opencpu.org/apps.html